# MalformedJwtException: JWT strings must contain exactly 2 period characters

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, react-redux, jwt, axios

I am creating a react project with a spring boot backend with jwt integrated in it.
Although i can get my register api to work over POSTMAN. It gives out a **MalformedJwtException** when I call my apis through the react app(through axios). A GET api call used to work even before i integrated the spring security to the backend.
I think its something to do with my HTTPClient.js file where its creating this issue.
here is it below

```
import axios from 'axios'

const id_token = "secret";
axios.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';

var instance = null;

export const setAuth = () => {
instance = axios.create({
    baseURL: '',
    timeout: 30000,

    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + localStorage.jwt,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
}
)

instance.interceptors.response.use(function (response) {
    return response;
}, function (error) {
    if (error.response.status === 401) {
        localStorage.removeItem('jwt');
        localStorage.removeItem('user');
        window.location = '/'
    }
    else {
        return Promise.reject(error);
    }
});
}

 export const Get=(route, data)=>{
    instance|| setAuth()

    return instance.get(route,data)
 }

 export const Post = (route, data) => {
  instance || setAuth()
  return instance.post(route, JSON.stringify(data))
 }

export const Put = (route, data) => {
instance || setAuth()
return instance.put(route, JSON.stringify(data))
}

export const Delete = (route, data) => {
instance || setAuth()
return instance.delete(route, JSON.stringify(data))
}
```

**EDIT**

```
cache-control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
connection: close
content-length: 0
date: Sat, 14 Dec 2019 14:47:21 GMT
expires: 0
pragma: no-cache
x-content-type-options: nosniff
x-frame-options: DENY
X-Powered-By: Express
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
POST /register HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:3000
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 193
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Origin: http://localhost:3000
Authorization: Bearer undefined
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.79 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/json
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Referer: http://localhost:3000/Welcome
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
```

this is my request header

Comment: please post what your request header looks like when sending it to the backend. You can do this by inspecting the request in your browser.

Comment: second of all, do not store a jwt in local storage. This will make your application susceptible to Cross Site Scripting attacks (XSS) . You should always use cookies with the HttpOnly flag set to true.

Comment: @ThomasAndolf I have added the request header. The bearer token is undefined but the spring security is asked to permit this request anyway

Comment: @ThomasAndolf and then you have to deal with CSRF.  There are risks using either approach.

Comment: @Joe i never said you will be fully protected, its the lesser evil of the choices you have.

Comment: Debatable.  Depending on how you handle your JWTs using LocalStorage is not a "don't do this" thing IMO.

Answer (score 0):

I tried with not sending an Authorization header at all in the request. Cannot have it as undefined, it simply shouldnt exist.